# Creating land area polygon from shoreline within chart border in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, qgis-processing, overlapping-features

I'm trying to create land area polygon from a shoreline within a chart border in QGIS, and there are some lakes that needs to be clipped from the land area. I've tried the "Lines to Polygon", but it didn't workout.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a polygon for the square and then using **Split With Lines** in the Processing Toolbox.

You can hand draw the square polygon or you can use **Print Layout to Map Extent** tool to create a rectangle polygon of your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a plug-in - `magic wand`, which can generate the desired layer with one click according to the color of the image, so that the surface layer is effective. If your coastline is a line layer, you can create a new rectangular line layer, merge it with the coastline, and then turn it into a surface layer. In this way, the plug-in will be effective.